# Coin Flipper not working

Tags: javascript, css, random

i was bored, so i made a coin flipper thing, but I can't get it to work!
i think the javascript thing works perfect, there is something wrong with the css stuff but I do not have any clue!

why is it not working?

here it is:

```js
// Buttons
var ButtonFlip = document.getElementById("btnFlip");
var ButtonReset = document.getElementById("btnreset");
var ButtonChange = document.getElementById("btnchange");

// Texts
var DisplayLastValue = document.getElementById("lastvalue");
var DisplayCounter = document.getElementById("countertext");

// Other Variables
var flipper = document.getElementById("flipper");
var Counter = 0;
var Degrees = 0;
var CoinValue = "Heads";

// Functions
ButtonFlip.onclick = function() {
 if (Counter >= 1) {
  Counter = Counter + 1;
  DisplayCounter.innerHTML = Counter;
  DisplayLastValue.innerHTML = CoinValue;
 } else {
  Counter = 1;
  DisplayCounter.innerHTML = Counter;
 }

 var Value = Math.random();

 console.log("Original value: " + Value);
  if (Value >= 0.5) {
   if (CoinValue == "Heads") {
     CoinValue = "Heads";
     Degrees += 1800;
     flipper.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
     flipper.style.MozTransform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
     flipper.style.msTransform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
     flipper.style.OTransform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
     flipper.style.transform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
   } else {
    CoinValue = "Tails";
     Degrees += 1800;
     flipper.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
     flipper.style.MozTransform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
     flipper.style.msTransform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
     flipper.style.OTransform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
     flipper.style.transform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
   }
  } else { // < 0.5
   if (CoinValue == "Heads") {
    CoinValue = "Tails";
     Degrees += 1620;
     flipper.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
     flipper.style.MozTransform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
     flipper.style.msTransform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
     flipper.style.OTransform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
     flipper.style.transform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
   } else if (CoinValue == "Tails")  {
     CoinValue = "Heads";
     Degrees += 1620;
     flipper.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
     flipper.style.MozTransform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
     flipper.style.msTransform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
     flipper.style.OTransform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
     flipper.style.transform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
   }
  }
  console.log(Degrees);
}

ButtonReset.onclick = function() {
 console.log("Reset!");
 Counter = 0;
 if (CoinValue == "Heads") {
 } else if (CoinValue == "Tails")  {
  Degrees += 180;
  flipper.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
  flipper.style.MozTransform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
  flipper.style.msTransform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
  flipper.style.OTransform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
  flipper.style.transform = "rotateY(" + Degrees + "deg)";
  CoinValue = "Heads";
 }
 DisplayCounter.innerHTML = "";
 DisplayLastValue.innerHTML = "";
 console.log(CoinValue);
 console.log(Degrees);
}
```

```css
html, body {
 background: url("https://googledrive.com/host/0B8o6WU--_6bocGJaOXpROEtzdGs") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.flip-container {
 width: 250px;
 height: 250px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.flipper {
 transition: 2s;
  -webkit-transition: 1.5s linear;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.coinfront, .coinback {
 width: 250px;
 height: 250px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
 border-radius: 100%;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
}

.coinfront {
  background-image: url('http://adrianspiegel.de/head.gif');
  background-size: 100%;
  @include rotateY(0deg);
  z-index: 99;
}

.coinback {
  background-image: url('http://adrianspiegel.de/tail.gif');
  background-size: 100%;
  @include rotateY(0deg);
  z-index: 99;
}

.buttons {
  border-radius: 20px; 
  height: 32px; 
  width: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin: 10px 10px 50px 10px;">
  <p>Number of flips: <b id="countertext"></b></p>
  <p>Previous value: <b id="lastvalue"></b></p>
  <div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper" id="flipper">
      <div class="coinfront" id="front">
      </div>
      <div class="coinback" id="back">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button id="btnFlip" class="buttons">
    Flip!
  </button>
  <button id="btnreset" class="buttons">
    Reset!
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please define "not working".

Comment: sometimes the coin disappears

Comment: Please explain your problem in details in the question itself.

Comment: your coin has two tails sides :) I don't see where you're changing the coin image.

Comment: The reason why is not visible for some of the cases is because you your cases is because the final state after the flip has been performed ends up in a position between tails and heads if you know what I mean.  Those are some of the angle values for which it stopped working: 3420 , 6660, 18900, 20700 .